# Path MTU is not always 9000, only in one direction

Tags: networking, local-area-network, mtu

I have a question about MTU or path MTU. In my setup I have 2 computers (firewall, Windows PC) and one NAS, each with a gigabit interface. They are connected throughout the same gigabit switch. In all of them I configured a MTU of 9000. Also activated "Jumbo Packets" on the interface of the Windows PC.
After measuring the path MTU with nmap I received a weird result:
 
 - When I messure from the NAS to the firewall and to the PC the result is 9000.
- When I messure from the firewall to the PC and to the NAS the result is 9000.
BUT
 - When I messure from the PC (Windows firewall on and off) to the firewall and to the NAS the result is 1492.
 

Do you have an explanation for these weird behavoir?

Comment: 1492 is the default value for windows and ethernet on windows

Comment: Ok, but I edited the MTU value of my ethernet interface and windows shows me this value in the status of the interface.

Comment: With "netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces" Windows shows me the 9000.

Comment: i think some device is not ablr to handle jumbo frames, even yozr switch must hsvr the ability to use them

Comment: It sounds like your PC NIC can't do jumbo frames -- even tho the software says it can.

Comment: I think that`s not the case. My NIC is an "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V" and it is suitable for jumo frames (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/82186/intel-ethernet-connection-i219-v.html).